# Lerna with Yarn Workspaces - How to build a complete node_modules

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, serverless, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I'm using Lerna with Yarn Workspaces and Serverless.

I'd like to be able to publish this package on Serverless which requires having a complete `node_modules` folder.

Is there any way to compile my local package with Lerna/Yarn in a way to get back the full `node_modules` folder without publishing the package on NPM?

Thanks